# preserve aspect ratio of x- and y- while scaling z-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

Let's say we want to plot function `f:ℝ² → ℝ` on a rectangular domain, let's say `[0,1] x [0,3]`, where `f` has values in the range `[-0.01,0.01]`. If we just use any plotting function like `mesh` or `surf` all the three axes are heavily distorted: All three axes are scaled such that everything fits in a cube. For instance

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:3);surf(x,y,sin(x).*cos(5./y)*0.01)
```

produces

[image: example]

Is there a way set the actual ratio of the x- and y- axes (such that the domain actually looks more like a 1x3-rectangle than a square) while preserving the automatic scaling in the z-axis?

(For example `axis equal` is *almost* what I need, but the z-axis gets also scaled, which I don't want.)

Answer (score -2):

It's not super elegant, but I would do this:

```
zLimits = get(gca,'ZLim');
axis equal;
set(gca, 'ZLim', zLimits);
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this does not work, as the axes get scaled together after `axis equal;`.